Mapping between vectors in irreducible Sp-representation
Let $V$ be the standard Sp-representation with symplectic basis $\{ a_i, b_i \}$. I believe the vector $(b_1 \wedge b_2) \otimes (b_1 \wedge b_2 \wedge a_3 \wedge a_4)$ lies inside the irreducible representation $\Gamma_{0,1,0,1} \subset \wedge^2 V \otimes \wedge^4 V$, since we can map it to the highest weight vector of $\Gamma_{0,1,0,1}$ via Sp-equivariant maps.
$(b_1 \wedge b_2) \otimes (a_3 \wedge a_4 \wedge a_5 \wedge b_1) \in \Gamma_{0,1,0,1}$ so we must be able to map from $(b_1 \wedge b_2) \otimes (b_1 \wedge b_2 \wedge a_3 \wedge a_4)$ to $(b_1 \wedge b_2) \otimes (a_3 \wedge a_4 \wedge a_5 \wedge b_1)$ via Sp-equivariant maps. Can someone help me find a composition of maps that does this?

What does "at least partially" mean here? Either it is in the representation or not and without knowing more about $\Gamma_{0,1,0,1}$ I wouldn't be sure that it is. Even if it is why would that mean we must have an equivariant map that sends it to a specific other element?

I edited my question. If an irreducible representation is the smallest Sp-invariant vector space containing its highest weight vector, should we be able to map between vectors in the representation using Sp-equivariant maps?

By Schur's Lemma the only equivariant automorphisms of an irrep are scales of the identity so if anything we know we definitely cannot do this.
